# multiline log (array) with logstash

Tags: logstash

I want to parse logfile with logstash which contains both single line and multiple line. [e.g first 2 lines with 1 line log entry whereas 3rd one has multiple line entry ]

```
ERROR - 2015-12-05 20:48:53 --> Could not find page
ERROR - 2015-12-05 20:48:53 --> Could not find VAR
ERROR - 2015-12-05 20:48:59 --> Array
(
    [id] => 12344
    [studentid] => 33
    [fname] => 
    [lname] =>
    [address] => tokyo
)
```

This log entry is forwarded from client (logstatsh-forwarder) which sets type as "multilineclient"

```
filter{
     if [type] == "multilineclient" {
        multiline {
        pattern => "^ERROR"
        what => "previous"
        }
    grok{
            match => {"message" => "%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s+%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s+%{DATA:message}({({[^}]+},?\s*)*})?\s*$(?<stacktrace>(?m:.*))?"}
   }

    mutate {
            remove => [ "@loglevel" ]
    }
}
}
```

I did try both Grok Debugger and grok constructer (but couldn't quite solve issue with LOGLEVEL being start of logfile ),

My multiline logs (array) are parsed as separate message.

```
message: [id] => 
message: [studentid] => 
message: [fname] =>
```

I was expecting this to come as single "message:"
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to get multiline{} (codec or filter) working properly.  When it does, you should end up with three documents based on your example.

Your multiline construct can be read as "when I find a line that begins with ERROR, keep it with the previous", which I don't think is what you want.  Sounds like you should add the 'negate' option.

If that solves the multiline problem, then you should run one grok{} to pull the common stuff off the front (level, date, time).  A second grok{} could then separate all the fields inside the parens from the rest.  The data inside the parens could probably be fed to the kv{} ("key value") filter to produce fields from the key/value pairs.